# Will the accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer in a smartphone work on the ISS?

Tags: iss

Curious as to how gyroscopic sensors, accelerometers and also magnetometers that are internal to the Nexus S smartphone on-board the ISS would work in a zero gravity environment.

Comment: http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/SmartPhones_Space.html

Answer (score 5):

The sensors should all function properly.  I guess you're asking how the phone would interpret them?

The phone is in a near-zero acceleration environment (freefall), so the accelerometers should show zero when it's not being pushed.

Gyroscopes would work normally to sense rotation.

The weaker magnetic field of the earth should be able to be sensed by the magnetometer (assuming it's not overwhelmed by nearby equipment), but the different shape at that altitude is going to make it horribly inaccurate.