# Can a smart phone function in space?

Tags: gravity

I recenty came a across a doubt...

Can a smart phone be used in space?

Obviously you aren't going to get any data signal, but will the functions like touch screen, GPS, accelerometer, vibrator, etc, work? Will anything get affected by gravity or no air?

Sid

Comment: Related: [Will the accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer in a smartphone work on the ISS?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/7728/4660)

Comment: So you mean in a vacuum, not in a space station or something?

Comment: https://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-in-spaaaace.html  (pressure at this altitude is approx 0.16 psi)

Comment: It would probably work fine as long as there was some sort of atmosphere, but in the vacuum of space, probably not so much, as air makes a pretty good dielectric. Granted smart phones don't work with very high voltages, but the space between runners is so small, it probably doesn't take a lot of voltage to arc between them in a vacuum.

Comment: GPS won't work, they're designed to stop working at high altitudes and high velocities so you can't use them to make ICBMs. See this: http://support.spectracom.com/articles/FAQ/Why-are-there-altitude-and-velocity-limits-for-GPS-equipment

Comment: I like climbing mountains. Often at a summit you'll run into other people, and sometimes there is cell reception, so you get people who are on their phones, going, "Hi! -- Hey, you'll never guess where I am! No, really, guess!" So I'm glad to hear that cell phones don't work in outer space, because the outer-space version of this story is just too depressing...

Comment: Related: [What level of radiation protection do electronics on the ISS or in LEO need?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17650/415), [Space computing, general question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4922/415), [Is the Pi really fit for outer space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15099/415) and to a lesser extent [What would be the (most difficult) challenge to make a “10,000 year satellite”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15320/415)

Comment: I speculate that the accelerometer would work, but any application code that accesses it could become confused as it reports that the device is in free fall for an extended period of time. The natural assumption for a device used on Earth is that a constant acceleration of 9.8 m/sec^2 in one direction means you're stationary.

Comment: related: [Did the NASA PhoneSat actually try to use the GPS from the phone itself?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15109/12102)

Comment: @Cody, that depends on the GPS unit.  Some manufacturers interpret the clause as "either high or fast", while others interpret it as "both high and fast".

Answer (score 3):

Multiple android based phone satellites have been launched into space. (At least six [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneSat)). I haven't looked into which components they tried using in orbit, but the camera obviously worked.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Take an ordinary smartphone and put it in outer space and you've got a big problem:  **Inadequate cooling.**  The phone is going to destroy itself with its own heat.  Normal conduction and convection cooling will not work, all you have is radiation and at those temperatures it's a small part of the cooling.

Also see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38614/12102) to *Do Phonesats and GoPros work with their internal batteries in space vacuum?*

Comment: So how does this information apply to the ones that have been successfully placed into space / near vacuum?  And still worked?

Comment: @OrganicMarble What are you talking about?  Nobody's launched a bare phone.  Now, a phone in a larger system can use that system as a heat sink--it's no longer in outer space but in a satellite.

Comment: https://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-in-spaaaace.html says they launched Nexus 5 phones in styrofoam coolers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's a high altitude balloon, not space.  The atmosphere is thin up there but it certainly exists.

Comment: 0.16 psi by my reference.  and Andew W's answer says that Phonesat 1 was Nexus 1 phones.

Comment: @OrganicMarble At the very least, the LCD display would stop working. Turns out the L in LCD stands for Liquid.

Comment: @Aron I'm not sure if you're right or not, but you would probably just disable the screen to save power / err on the side of caution.

Comment: @AndrewW the LCD display would sublime off. Turn it off does nothing. But it was tongue in cheek, as there is no one to look at the LCD display in space. If an LCD panel sublimes in space, and no one is looking, does it really break?

Comment: I've just asked [How do phonesats stay cool?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45190/12102)

Comment: the question is about functioning in space, not functioning in a vacuum... The ISS is in space, but the inside of it is not a vacuum and the phone would function there if there's a GSM mast installed within the ISS (that would have to relay through a satellite comms network).

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the other answers, the GPS in a typical smartphone will not work in space--or more specifically orbit--because consumer GPS units have restrictions placed in their firmware which prevent their functioning above a certain altitude and/or speed. A military or scientific-grade GPS would still function though, and GPS is in fact used by many satellites and the ISS.

Comment: by that logic, the GSM system also wouldn't work because it'd be out of range of GSM networks which are earth bound and have antennae carefully designed to minimise radiation upward in order to conserve power.